# Connect to database in AWS RDS, error invalid database address:

Tags: java, database, jdbc, amazon-web-services, rds

I am trying to connect to AWS RDS database via jdbc. But got the error:
java.sql.SQLException: invalid database address: jdbc:mysql://data.cbw2ndcwkqkc.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306;databaseName=data;user=xx;password=xxx;

I can connect the database via mysql.

part of my code:

```
String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://data.cbw2ndcwkqkc.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306;" + "databaseName=data;user=xx;password=xxx;";

Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

c = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

Really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are typos in your `connectionUrl`. Try:

1. Replace the `;` after the `3306` port number with `/`.
2. Replace all subsequent `;` delimiters which separates the username and password parameters with `&`.
3. Replace your `databaseName=data` parameter with just `/data`.
4. Confirm your endpoint URL.

Like this:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://<your_instance_endpoint>:3306/" + "<your_database_name>?user=xx&password=xxx";
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, actually i replaced the database with another database which is not in aws, that works. but when i use aws database, it shows invalid database

Comment: Make sure the endpoint and database name in your URL is correct. You can find the full endpoint in the 'Detail View' of your database instance. Also, there is no `databaseName` parameter in a JDBC URL.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. If you use mysql connector 5.1.40 or above, you must be replace to 5.1.40.
2. Check your jdbc package duplicate (ex: sqlite-jdbc), and remove it.
3. Refresh